# How to use listview in a widget?

Tags: android, listview, widget

I am trying to create a listview loaded from rss feeds into a widget?

Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to use a listview in a wigdet?

Or maybe someone could provide 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to create a listview loaded from rss feeds into a widget?

This is only possible on Honeycomb. Earlier versions of Android did not support this, and it remains to be seen if it will be supported on phones going forward.

> Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to use a listview in a wigdet?

The WeatherListWidget sample is in your SDK and is lightly explained [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/index.html).

Comment: So what would be the work around to work on Phones and Tablets?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22: That is impossible to answer in the abstract. Generally speaking, you don't show things that look like lists in app widgets as the "workaround".

Answer (score 11):

Basically, you need to use two components:

1. **RemoteViewsFactory**: This is the especial adapter.
2. **RemoteViewsService**: This is to return the first one.

Let's create the RemoteViewsFactory class:

```
public class MyWidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public MyWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(Context applicationContext, Intent intent) {
        mContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.close();
        }

        final long identityToken = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        Uri uri = Contract.PATH_TODOS_URI;
        mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                Contract._ID + " DESC");

        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identityToken);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCursor == null ? 0 : mCursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        if (position == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION ||
                mCursor == null || !mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return null;
        }

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.collection_widget_list_item);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetItemTaskNameLabel, mCursor.getString(1));

        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mCursor.moveToPosition(position) ? mCursor.getLong(0) : position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now it's time for the RemoteViewsService (the easy one):

```
public class MyWidgetRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new MyWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}
```

Also you must register this service in the androidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".AppWidget.MyWidgetRemoteViewsService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"></service>
```

And now in your Widget class which extends AppWidgetProvider, you can manage the layouts:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.collection_widget
        );
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetRemoteViewsService.class);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widgetListView, intent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Now create a new resource file in **res/xml** and name it collection_widget.xml:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="864000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/simple_widget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/collection_widget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

We need to create two more files in **res/layout** to define the layout of the list and the layout of each list item.

**collection_widget.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/widgetTitleLabel"
            android:text="@string/title_collection_widget"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_title_min_height"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/widgetListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:divider="#eeeeee"
            tools:listitem="@layout/collection_widget_list_item"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**collection_widget_list_item.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/widget_listview_padding_x"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/widget_listview_padding_x"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/widget_listview_padding_x"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/widget_listview_padding_x"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/widget_listview_item_height"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/widgetItemContainer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/widgetItemTaskNameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

I use this article like example and works like a charm for me!!

https://www.sitepoint.com/killer-way-to-show-a-list-of-items-in-android-collection-widget/

Now a days, this is not that rare. Hope to help someone.

Comment: @Slashhh Please include the relevant information in the answer itself, because if tomorrow this link changes/removed than it would make this answer invalid, that's why link-only answers are not allowed

Comment: @alon-eitan, Ok, done!!