# Android LIstview inside a widget

Tags: android, listview, widget

i am creating a widget in android where i need to use a list view . 
Is it possible to put a list view in a widget ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313785/how-to-use-listview-in-a-widget/50001127

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I used this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

code to learn from commonsGuy - pretty good base to start with!

Comment: Note that this only works on API Level 11 (Android 3.0) and higher. App widgets do not support `ListView` on earlier versions of Android.